# Find a Text Value, Offset, Enter Formula based on OffSet Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have another VBA question please.

1. I have a Table in Excel,  I want to find the text: "All Other" that will always be in Column B, but may not be in the same Row #.
2. After I find "All Other" cell, I want to enter a Sum formula in the next column over (0,1).
3. The formula would Sum the unknown range starting with 3 rows down from the Activecell to the end of the data.

I'm getting an error: Invalid or unqualified reference.

**PrintScreen**:

[image]

I currently have:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aOther As Range
Dim DataLastRow As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set DataLastRow = ws.Cells.Range(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows

    Set aOther = ws.Range("B:B").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & .Offset(3, 0) & DataLastRow & ")"
```

Comment: `aOther.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 0).Address & ":" & ws.cells(DataLastRow,3).Address & ")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner - `DataLastRow` is a range... so yeah...

Comment: @BigBen I missed that: `aOther.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 0).Address & ":" & DataLastRow.Address & ")"` and get rid of the `.Rows` on the `Set DataLastRow` line.

Comment: Well you'd have to change it to column C right (`DataLastRow` is in A)?

Comment: @BigBen yes: `Set DataLastRow = ws.Cells.Range(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)`

Comment: ^ and drop the `.Range` too :-)

Comment: `Set DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)`

Comment: I'm wanting to copy the formula over to other columns, and I need to make sure to cover the last row in the table which is always filled by Column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aOther As Range
Dim DataLastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet

DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set aOther = ws.Range("B:B").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not aOther is Nothing Then
        aOther.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 1).Address & ":" & ws.Cells(DataLastRow,3).Address & ")"
    Else
        MsgBox """All Other"" not found in column."
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!  I do have a couple of questions please.  I am brand new to VBA, and learning through Google and Trial by Fire.  

1) I just need to look for "All Other" once, since it will always be in Column B.  How do I perform this without a loop?

Comment: 2) I had the `DataLastRow` set up to reference Column A, because there will always be Data to the end of Column A in the table. Column C won't necessarily have Data to the end.  

(I did this, because the next step would be to copy the Formula into Column D, E, G, H, I, J, and L `Offset – 0 Rows`).

Comment: 3) For my learning purposes: Why am I able to drop the `.Range` and `.Rows` on the `Set DataLastRow`?   Wouldn’t I need to reference the Table Range?

Comment: 1. there is no loop in the code.  2.I fixed the code to now look in column A. 3 `Cells()` is a range object and does not need the `Range` if referring to the location on the entire sheet.  `Range("C1:D5").Cells(1,1)` would refer to `Range ("C1")` without the Range(address) it refers to the whole sheet.  `Rows` refers to all the rows in the given range, where you were trying to return `Row` which is a `Long` not a `Range`

Comment: Thank you so much!  Would you also be able to tell me how to copy the formula from the unknown Active Cell and paste it into the adjoining Column D, E, G, H, I, J, and L `Offset – 0 Rows`?

Comment: @CariDay new questions get new posts.